# how to display overall dimensions for furniture

Tags: dimensions

[image: example image for visual reference]

Is there a way to display a furniture design’s overall dimensions in Blender 3D for the purpose of presentation?  Please see attachment for visual.

When I import a wrl file into Blender, the furniture design consists of many parts.  The only way I know how to get the bounding box for the entire furniture is by joining all parts.  However, there seems to be no way to get the bounding box to illustrate its dimensions.  In Solidworks, the bound box can display dimensions.  Is there a similar function in Blender 3D?  Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

In your specific case, the *MeasureIt addon* makes sense.
However, there are also different ways to measure stuff inside Blender UI.

- Measure Tool *(length and angles, set by mouse drag)*
- Measurement Overlay *(measurement of selected geometry, like bounding boxes)*

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer!  I did not know about "Edge Length" under viewport overlays.  But since the furniture designs I work with consist of many parts, "Edge Length" displays the dimensions for every single part,  enabling "Edge Length" led to an undecipherable cluster of numbers.  I will post my follow-up question where I can post photos for visual.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like there is an addon called "MeasureIt Tools" that comes built in to Blender, you just need to enable it in the add-ons section of the preferences. Check this video out.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=R0jCdCoaRvs

Los

Comment: Thank you very much.  I will post a follow-up question with photos attached for visual.